# My AdonisJs migrations are not generating any tables in the Workbech

Tags: javascript, mysql, sqlite, database-migration, adonis.js

I'm trying to run some migrations using AdonisJS and MySQL (sqlite3), but it seems that when i run the migrations they're not generating any tables in my Workbench even though i get the message "Databease migrated sucessfully". My .env file and the SQL connection in the workbech have the port 3306 and the SQL service is running properly, what could be causing it? If you guys need me to share any files just ask in the comments.

`.env` file:

```
HOST=127.0.0.1
PORT=3333
NODE_ENV=development
        
APP_NAME=AdonisJs
APP_URL=http://${HOST}:${PORT}
        
CACHE_VIEWS=false
        
APP_KEY=
        
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3308
DB_USER=root
DB_PASSWORD=cdebanco3soft
DB_DATABASE=adonis
        
HASH_DRIVER=bcrypt
```

`config/database.js`:

```js
'use strict'

/** @type {import('@adonisjs/framework/src/Env')} */
const Env = use('Env')

/** @type {import('@adonisjs/ignitor/src/Helpers')} */
const Helpers = use('Helpers')

module.exports = {
   /*
   |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   | Default Connection
   |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |
   | Connection defines the default connection settings to be used while
   | interacting with SQL databases.
   |
   */
   connection: Env.get('DB_CONNECTION', 'sqlite'),

   /*
   |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   | Sqlite
   |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |
   | Sqlite is a flat file database and can be a good choice for a development
   | environment.
   |
   | npm i --save sqlite3
   |
   */
   sqlite: {
     client: 'sqlite3',
     connection: {
       filename: Helpers.databasePath(`${Env.get('DB_DATABASE', 'development')}.sqlite`)
     },
     useNullAsDefault: true,
     debug: Env.get('DB_DEBUG', false)
   },

   /*
   |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   | MySQL
   |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |
   | Here we define connection settings for MySQL database.
   |
   | npm i --save mysql
   |
   */
   mysql: {
     client: 'mysql',
     connection: {
       host: Env.get('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
       port: Env.get('DB_PORT', ''),
       user: Env.get('DB_USER', 'root'),
       password: Env.get('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
       database: Env.get('DB_DATABASE', 'adonis')
     },
     debug: Env.get('DB_DEBUG', false)
   },

   /*
   |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   | PostgreSQL
   |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |
   | Here we define connection settings for PostgreSQL database.
   |
   | npm i --save pg
   |
   */
   pg: {
     client: 'pg',
     connection: {
       host: Env.get('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
       port: Env.get('DB_PORT', ''),
       user: Env.get('DB_USER', 'root'),
       password: Env.get('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
       database: Env.get('DB_DATABASE', 'adonis')
     },
     debug: Env.get('DB_DEBUG', false)
   }
 }
```

Comment: Sqlite do not use a port for communication, it's basically a file. Can you please share your `config/database.[ts or js]`, your `.env` and the full logs output (we need more information to help you). Thanks

Comment: both the .env and the config/database are now in the post, but i'm not sure where to find theses logs

Comment: thanks. Just add you console log output. 
If you use sqlite drivers, your sqlite database is in your `database` folder (`database/adonis.sqlite`)

Comment: The adonis.sqlite file is encrypted here

Comment: Adonis don't encrypt sqlite database by default, are you sure it's encrypted? Try open database with tool like DBeaver or Beekeeper Studio.

Comment: Yes, i'm 100% sure of that, but i'll still try to use these tools you mentioned